# How to make the if statement without repetition of code?

Tags: javascript

Following is the if statement that execute some part of the code before it checks some condition, it is working fine but it looks very basic and repeated lines.

```
    if(allTasks[t].status === "Completed"){
        arrow.setAttribute("class","arrow2");
        tag.setAttribute("class","completed");
        tag.innerHTML = allTasks[t].status;
        taskCont.appendChild(tag);
    }else if(allTasks[t].status === "Past Due"){
        arrow.setAttribute("class","arrow2");
        tag.setAttribute("class","pastdue");
        tag.innerHTML = allTasks[t].status;
        taskCont.appendChild(tag);
    }else if(allTasks[t].status === "Duetoday"){
        arrow.setAttribute("class","arrow2");
        tag.setAttribute("class","duetoday");
        tag.innerHTML = allTasks[t].status;
        taskCont.appendChild(tag);
    }else if(allTasks[t].status === "Onhold"){
        arrow.setAttribute("class","arrow2");
        tag.setAttribute("class","onhold");
        tag.innerHTML = allTasks[t].status;
        taskCont.appendChild(tag);
    }else if(allTasks[t].status === "Canceled"){
        arrow.setAttribute("class","arrow2");
        tag.setAttribute("class","canceled");
        tag.innerHTML = allTasks[t].status;
        taskCont.appendChild(tag);
    }
```

Comment: Only one of the four lines inside seems to change at all, and it can be simplified to `allTasks[t].status.toLowerCase()`. If those conditions are exhaustive, you don't need them at all.

Comment: do you have other values for `status` than above?

Comment: You repeat 3 lines of code in every `if/else`, a good start is to move those to after your `if {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code this will save your if statements

```
var status = allTasks[t].status;
arrow.setAttribute("class","arrow2");
tag.setAttribute("class",status.replace(/ /g,'').toLowerCase());
tag.innerHTML = status;
taskCont.appendChild(tag);
```

Comment: You'll need to remove the space for "Past Due" to "pastdue" : `.replace(/\s/g, '') `

Comment: that also applies to my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `switch` statement.

```
switch(expression) {
  case x:
    // code block
    break;
  case y:
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

You should also remove duplicated code from the conditions, like this:

```
arrow.setAttribute("class","arrow2");
tag.innerHTML = allTasks[t].status;
taskCont.appendChild(tag);

switch (allTasks[t].status) {
  case "Completed":
    tag.setAttribute("class","completed");
    break;
  case "Past Due":
    tag.setAttribute("class","pastdue");
    break;
  case "Duetoday":
    tag.setAttribute("class","duetoday");
    break;
  case "Onhold":
    tag.setAttribute("class","onhold");
    break;
  case "Canceled":
    tag.setAttribute("class","canceled");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var statusList={
    'Completed':{
        'arrowClass':'arrow2',
        'tagClass':'completed'
    },
    'Past Due':{
        'arrowClass':'arrow2',
        'tagClass':'pastdue'
    }
}
```

With this structure You can do something like this:

```
arrow.setAttribute("class",statusList[allTasks[t].status]["arrowClass"]);
tag.setAttribute("class",statusList[allTasks[t].status]["tagClass"]);
tag.innerHTML = allTasks[t].status;
```

Answer (score 0):

1)You can put out of the 'if' the sentences that are repeated:

```
arrow.setAttribute("class","arrow2");
tag.innerHTML = allTasks[t].status;
taskCont.appendChild(tag);
if(allTasks[t].status === "Completed"){

    tag.setAttribute("class","completed");

}else if(allTasks[t].status === "Past Due"){

    tag.setAttribute("class","pastdue");

}else if(allTasks[t].status === "Duetoday"){

    tag.setAttribute("class","duetoday");

}else if(allTasks[t].status === "Onhold"){

    tag.setAttribute("class","onhold");

}else if(allTasks[t].status === "Canceled"){

    tag.setAttribute("class","canceled");

}
```

2) (much more specific to *your* code) if you notice, inside setAttribute you're entering the lowered case of your status

```
tag.setAttribute("class",allTasks[y].status.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ''));
arrow.setAttribute("class","arrow2");
tag.innerHTML = allTasks[t].status;
taskCont.appendChild(tag);
```

Comment: see @brett-gregson comment

Answer (score 0):

```
updateTask(status, arrow, tag, taskCont) {
  arrow.setAttribute("class","arrow2");
  tag.setAttribute("class",status.toLowerCase());
  tag.innerHTML = allTasks[t].status;
  taskCont.appendChild(tag);
}

updateTask(allTasks[t].status, arrow, tag, taskCont)
```

Notice the `status.toLowerCase()` bit.

If you want to tone down the fragility of this you can use an Enum to map the status to the correct corresponding tag attribute.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate function for setting attribues to the element and the call it in a switch statement:

```js
function setAttrs(element, status) {
  element.setAttribute("class", status);
  element.innerHTML = status;
  return element;
}

function yourFunction {
  // ...

  // since you call it every time, keep it at the top, it will be executed once
  arrow.setAttribute("class", "arrow2");

  switch (allTasks[t].status) {
    case "Completed":
      let tagUpdated = setAttrs(tag, "completed")
      taskCont.appendChild(tagUpdated);
      break;
    case "Past Due":
      let tagUpdated = setAttrs(tag, "pastdue")
      taskCont.appendChild(tagUpdated);
      break;
    case "Duetoday":
      let tagUpdated = setAttrs(tag, "duetoday")
      taskCont.appendChild(tagUpdated);
      break;
    case "Onhold":
      let tagUpdated = setAttrs(tag, "onhold")
      taskCont.appendChild(tagUpdated);
      break;
    case "Canceled":
      let tagUpdated = setAttrs(tag, "canceled")
      taskCont.appendChild(tagUpdated);
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function statusToAttrib(v){
    return v.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'')
}

arrow.setAttribute("class","arrow2");
tag.setAttribute("class",statusToAttrib(allTasks[t].status));
tag.innerHTML = allTasks[t].status;
taskCont.appendChild(tag);
```